# How to store Firebase children node-names in an array of strings?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to compare the efficiency of querying in normalized databases in Firebase versus denormalized databases (recommended by the creators), while accessing the data from Swift 2. Let's say I have a normalized database

[image]

and I want to store all the values (i.e., the children node names) in the n-th branch in an array of strings, what would be the most efficient way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the array would look like for, say, Level 2?

Comment: Array for Level 2 would be = [Level 3] (since there is just one child node). 
Array for Level 3 would be = [Level 4, Level 5, Level 6]